# Python: search, and join

Tags: python, pandas

I have 2 dataframe(data1 and data2).
data2 is the list of countries.
data1 is the list of companies.
In the data2, I purposely duplicate one of the country
I want to add new column(country namme) in the data1.
I can do it with groupby, drop_duplicate, and merge. But this code is too long.
Is there a simple way to solve this join and retrieve the value from different dataframe
example code:

```
data1 = {
         'Code': [1, 2, 3],
         'Name': ['Company1', 'Company2', 'Company3'],
         'CountryCode': [61,62,64],

    }
df1 = pd.DataFrame(data1, columns= ['Code','Name','CountryCode'])

data2 = {
         'CountryCode': ['61','62','64','62'],
         'Country': ['Australia','Indonesia','NewZealand','Indonesia'],
    }
df2 = pd.DataFrame(data2, columns= ['CountryCode','Country'])
print(df1)
   Code      Name  CountryCode
0     1  Company1           61
1     2  Company2           62
2     3  Company3           64

print(df2)

  CountryCode     Country
0          61   Australia
1          62   Indonesia
2          64  NewZealand
3          62   Indonesia

What I want the output is for df1
   Code      Name  CountryCode Country
0     1  Company1           61 Australia
1     2  Company2           62 Indonesia
2     3  Company3           64 NewZealand
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
country_dict = dict(zip(df2['CountryCode'], df2['Country']))
df1['Country'] = df1['CountryCode'].map(country_dict)
```

**Note**: In the input you have provided, column `CountryCode` is integer in df1 but object in df2. If this really how the data is, use the code below.
If the datatype is same in booth data-frames, you can use the code above.

```
df1['Country'] = df1['CountryCode'].astype(str).map(country_dict)
```

**Output**

```
  Code     Name     CountryCode     Country
0   1   Company1    61              Australia
1   2   Company2    62              Indonesia
2   3   Company3    64              NewZealand
```

Comment: thk for the reply moys.
I run your code, and the country inside data1 are Nan. 
output:
 Code Name CountryCode Country
0 1 Company1 61                 NaN
1 2 Company2 62                 NaN
2 3 Company3 64                 NaN

Comment: please check the full code, i have included a note now.

Comment: Awesome solution. Thk you very much moys.
I am trying to learn python.
what if the key is different title. in the df1, called country_code and df2 called countrycode

Comment: It should not matter.  `country_dict` does not have the column name. Print `country_dict ` & see the output, you will get an idea. Just make sure to use the correct name while creating the dictionary.